# Looping through lines in a text file with python

Tags: python, csv, text, text-files

I receive text files that are structured like this:

```
random
----new data-----
06/19/2018 13:57:39.99 random information here
06/19/2018 13:58:24.99 some more random info
06/19/2018 13:58:35.08  00:00:04.38 A 00000 0 765 228270257 A0   44    45
06/19/2018 13:58:39.99  00:00:00.00 A 00000 0 756 228270257 A0    4     5
06/19/2018 13:58:40.61  00:00:00.00 A 00000 0 828 228270257 A0    1     7
06/19/2018 13:57:39.99 random information here
06/19/2018 13:58:24.99 some more random info
---end data---
random stuff
```

There are several lines with random information surrounding the actual data I care about. I only want to keep the rows that have `A` in the fourth row, and then I want to turn the data into a CSV file.

Assuming the data above is in `play.txt`, I have tried several variants of this. which isn't working:

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

id = []
with open('play.txt', 'r') as fi:
    for ln in fi:
        if ln.startswith("A",4):
            id.append(ln[0:])


id2 = ' '.join(id)
df = pd.read_table(StringIO(id2), delimiter=r'\s+', header=None)


print(df)
                   
df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

How can this be done in python?

Comment: what is the file delimiter?

Comment: Why do you think `if ln.startswith("A",4)` will work? First you will need to split `ln` and then check the 4th element. Try something like `if ln.split()[3] == "A":`

Comment: @Dan that could be not enough ex:"06/19/2018 13:58:24.99 god! a bug". better to check at least the syntax of all the element of the line, or even better, the semantics

Comment: @hpchavaz, the OP asked just to check if it was A, not for any syntax check, so that is not really relevant. To check, we would need regex though, which is a bit overkill.

Comment: "I only want to keep the rows that have A in the fourth row" I assume you mean the 4th _column_.

Comment: I would probably just filter the file with `open('out.csv','w').writelines(line for line in open('play.txt') if ' A ' in line)` and load it into whatever you want as a csv, specifying the delimiter as space. The use of pandas and all these iterators is overkill.

Comment: @hpchavaz that's a good edge case, the OP is underspecified

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# read the file
file = open('play.txt').read()

id = []

# loop through the file and if the fourth word is 'A' then append that line to 'id'
for line in file.splitlines():
    if line.split()[3] == 'A':
        id.append(line.split())

# save to a dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(id)
df
    0           1           2           3   4       5   6   7           8   9   10
0   06/19/2018  13:58:35.08 00:00:04.38 A   00000   0   765 228270257   A0  44  45
1   06/19/2018  13:58:39.99 00:00:00.00 A   00000   0   756 228270257   A0  4   5
2   06/19/2018  13:58:40.61 00:00:00.00 A   00000   0   828 228270257   A0  1   7

# if you want specify column names too 
# df = pd.DataFrame(id, columns=['col_name_1', 'col_name_2'... ])

# save to csv
df.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Comment: when I try this on my actual data file, I get the following error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/....", line 11, in <module>
    if line.split()[3] == 'A':
IndexError: list index out of range` some lines in the file have less than 3 rows, could that be why?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```py
with open('play.txt', 'r') as fi:
    for line in fi:
        line = line.split(" ") 
        # you can also use line.split() to split 
        # the line by all whitespace.
        if (len(line)>=4 and line[3]=="A"):
            ...
```

This splits by the spaces, and then you can use the list indexing.

**Why `ln.startswith("A",4)` doesn't work**

That code doesn't work for 2 main reasons.

1. Python starts 0 indexed, so if you were looking for the 4th column, you would write `ln.startswith("A", 3)`
2. `ln.startswith("A", 3)` gets the literal 4th character in the string. Python reads the line in as a string of characters, which consists of the text that you have. So, using `ln.startswith("A", 3)` gets the 4th character, which, in all of the lines, is the character "1".