# Split large excel worksheet into several files

Tags: excel, parsing

I have two large excel document that has two sheets, each with a large amount of columns (one goes to column BTF and one to ECA). The worksheet data repeats itself every three columns in the following format:

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpWO8.png)

I would like to pull each of these repeating sets of three columns into its own .csv file. Is there a VBA or python script that could help do this?

I have tried running a VBA script that separates into worksheets within the file but it becomes too large and crashes the computer.

Comment: Maybe a customization of this code would help https://trumpexcel.com/split-each-excel-sheet-into-separate-files/

Comment: You seem to have fixed width data. Each chunk seems about 50chrs. Export to CSV. Parse the file with whatever language you are most comfortable with. Loop thru each row of text. For each row send every 50chrs to its own file.

Comment: Python text parsing example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67269909/looping-through-lines-in-a-text-file-with-python

Comment: Power Query is an option too.